# Triskadecimal Emojis

Tags: logical-deduction, formation-of-numbers

[This puzzle is heavily based on one from video game Zero Time Dilemma.]

I have one of those weird individualist friends--to give you an idea, he spells his name H-E-N--R-Y. ...The  is silent, y'see.

Anyway, he's easy enough to talk to but, like most people around this generation, he insists on texting.  And the thing is, he uses his own number system--it's base-13 and, furthermore, is expressed entirely in emojis.  It's always difficult to settle on a time to meet when he says he's available at :.

I've managed to figure out these rules.

> is greater than , which is greater than .
>
> times  equals .
>
> times  times  equals .
>
> equals  times .
>
> Anything multiplied by  is .
>
> times  equals .
>
> times  is .
>
> times  equals .

***From here, can you determine what emojis correspond to what numbers, 0-C (zero through 12, base ten)?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> = 0  (because  * x = )

Because

> equals  times   we know
>   = 2 or 3
>   = 4 or 9

But

> times  is 
>  so  must be 4 because 9 x something > 1 would be too large
>  This means  = 2

So

> 2 times  times 2 equals . 
>  Which means  can be 1 or 3
>  And  is 4 or 12.   But 4 is , so  is 12 and  is 3

Thus

> times  equals .  Means
>   = 9

And

> times  is  means  is 8
>    times  equals . Means  = 6

Because

> 2 times  equals .
>    must be 5 based on what’s left and  = 10

And

> is greater than , which is greater than  means
>    = 1,  = 7 and  = 11 because they are the only ones left

So

> = 0
>   = 1
>   = 2
>   = 3
>   = 4
>   = 5
>   = 6
>   = 7
>   = 8
>   = 9
>   = 10
>   = 11
>   is 12

Comment: Well done!  I think you solved this faster than I did in the game (which had the advantage of better-organized clues and prime factoring in its number construction).